# Why is $i:l^p(J)\hookrightarrow l^q(J), u\mapsto u$, $1\le p\le q\le \infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $J$ be a countable set. Prove that $i:l^p(J)\hookrightarrow l^q(J), u\mapsto u$,  $1\le p\le q\le \infty$.

I used that $\|x\|_q\le\|x\|_p$ for all $1\le p\le q\le \infty$ (I had to prove this inequalty too) to justify that i is well-defined and continuous. Clearly, $i$ is linear and injective.
I already proved that $\|x\|_q\le\|x\|_1$ (this was a hint). How can I deduce the inequality $\|x\|_q\le\|x\|_p$ for all $1\le p\le q\le \infty$?

1)What else I have to prove that $i$ is an embedding?

2)Why is $l^q(J)\hookrightarrow l^p(J)$ not true in general? I think it satisfies to find a sequence $x\in l^{\infty}(J)$, such that $x\notin l^1(J)$. I would take $x$ the sequence which is constant 1, then $x$ is bounded but does not converge to $0$. Is it correct?

Comment: I am unsure what you are asking. Usually, in Banach space theory, the notation $X\hookrightarrow Y$ means that $Y$ contains an isomorphic copy of $Y$, and $i:X\hookrightarrow Y$ means that $i$ is an isomorphism from $X$ onto its copy in $Y$.  But $\ell_p$ and $\ell_q$ are totally incomparable whenever $p\neq q$, and certainly neither one contains a copy of the other.  On the other hand, if $1\leq p\leq q\leq\infty$ then $\ell_p$ is a sub**set** of $\ell_q$. However if $1\leq q<p\leq\infty$ then this is not true, as you could take $(n^{-1/q})_{n=1}^\infty\in\ell_p\setminus\ell_q$.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the hint to $( | x_n |^{r/q})_n$:
$$
(\sum |x_n|^r)^{1/q} = (\sum (|x_n|^{r/q})^q)^{1/q} \le \sum |x_n|^{r/q},
$$
then rise to the power $q/r$ to get $\|x\|_r \le \|x\|_{r/q}$, and set properly $q$ and $r$ to get the claim.
Notice that you used the fact that $q>1$ to prove the hint, thus the inequality holds with the implicit condition $r/q < r$.